# Get previous month's last day and if its not Saturday then get all the dates till saturday (incl Sat)

Tags: powershell

1. Get last day of the previous month.
2. If its not Saturday (of that week) then get all dates from the last day (whatever the dayofweek it is) till Saturday of that week (in yyyymmdd format)

For Example:

IF i am running the script on the 7th and the 14th of September 2016 then my script should first find the last day of previous month which is 20160831 (Wednesday).

Now it should get me all the dates from the last day till Saturday of that week (including Saturday)

20160901
20160902
20160903

I would to store each of the dates in different variables to be used later in the script.

I have figured how to get the last day of the previous month (in the right format) but i cant figure out how to get the dates from that day till Saturday.

This script needs to be dynamic as i would like to schedule it to run every month.

`Param ([system.Datetime] $date = $(get-date)) $numdays = $date.Day $lastday = $date.AddDays(-$numdays) $lastday = $date.AddDays(-$numdays).DayOfWeek`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Get the first day of this month at midnight, and step back a day to the last day of the previous month
${Date Stepper} = (Get-Date -Day 1 -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0 -Millisecond 0).AddDays(-1)

# Step forward, one day at a time, output the last day of the month until the following Saturday
$Counter = 1
Do
{

    ${Date Stepper} = ${Date Stepper}.AddDays(1)
    Set-Item -Path "Variable:Var$Counter" -Value ${Date Stepper}.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
    $Counter++

} While ([System.DayOfWeek]::Saturday -gt ${Date Stepper}.DayOfWeek)

# Test Outputs
Write-Host "Var1 = $Var1"
Write-Host "Var2 = $Var2"
Write-Host "Var3 = $Var3"
Write-Host "Var4 = $Var4"
Write-Host "Var5 = $Var5"
Write-Host "Var6 = $Var6"
Write-Host "Var7 = $Var7"
```

Comment: That's an amazing way to do it, i was trying so many different ways of doing this which would have made my script really long. How can i exclude the last day of the month from the output? Also, can i store the days in the output to independent variables? For ex: at the moment the output is Wed, Thus, Fri & Sat. In this case i want the output to only have Thus, Fri & Sat and have them stored in 3 different variables `$day1 = "Thus"  $day2 = Fri  $day3 = Sat` .. Also i want these variables to have them stored in yyyymmdd format?

Comment: "*How can i exclude the last day of the month from the output?*" - so if the last day is Saturday, you want no output? I adjusted it to `-2` days so you would definitely get the last day and always get some output. Change that on the first code line to -1 instead (I'll edit).

Comment: I understand what you mean but if its Saturday then i dont need to do anything. Only when the last day doesnt fall on a Saturday would i want to get the days from the last day (excluding ) till Saturday (including). I have changed to -1 and it now gives 3 days in this scenario. how can i get the value of this output stored in 3 different variables in yyyymmdd format?

Comment: I've updated it to put the date in `yyyyMMdd` format (`mm` is minutes, `MM` is months), and put the values into new variables instead of an array even though that's going to be really difficult to work with because you'll never know which of them has a value, and you'll have seven lots of copy-paste code bloating your script, and the variable allocation won't be clear or highlighted in your code editor and can't be searched for because the variable names are set at runtime, and the whole approach will be unfamiliar and confusing to anyone else trying to maintain it.

Comment: You're the boss!! Thank you so much !! Thats exactly what i was after!! :) ... It works like a charm !!

Comment: May i ask why do you have ${Date Stepper} inside curly braces? Why cant it be $DateStepper instead?

Comment: IJustFeltLikeIt;WantedToSeeWhatCodeLookedLikeWithProperSpacesInsteadOfEverythingLookingLikeThis.ItCanBeLikeThatInstead.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust code like the following to meet your needs.

```
function Get-PreviousMonthEndToSaturday
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
    [DateTime]
    $LookbackDate
    )

    $retDates = @()

    Write-Verbose "LookbackDate: $($LookbackDate.ToLongDateString())"

    # prior month
    $date = $LookbackDate.AddMonths(-1)
    # all months have 28 days
    $date = [DateTime]::new($date.Year, $date.Month, 28)

    # while in current month...
    while ($date.Month -eq $date.AddDays(1).Month)
    {
        $date = $date.AddDays(1)
    }

    # while day is not Sunday...
    while ($date.DayOfWeek -ne [System.DayOfWeek]::Sunday)
    {
        $retDates += $date
        $date = $date.AddDays(1)
    }

    # return desired dates
    return $retDates
}

Get-PreviousMonthEndToSaturday ([DateTime]::Now) -Verbose
Get-PreviousMonthEndToSaturday ([DateTime]::Parse("2016/7/15")) -Verbose
# April ends on a Saturday
Get-PreviousMonthEndToSaturday ([DateTime]::Parse("2016/5/3")) -Verbose
```

Outputs:

```
VERBOSE: LookbackDate: Thursday, September 1, 2016
Wednesday, August 31, 2016 12:00:00 AM
Thursday, September 1, 2016 12:00:00 AM
Friday, September 2, 2016 12:00:00 AM
Saturday, September 3, 2016 12:00:00 AM
VERBOSE: LookbackDate: Friday, July 15, 2016
Thursday, June 30, 2016 12:00:00 AM
Friday, July 1, 2016 12:00:00 AM
Saturday, July 2, 2016 12:00:00 AM
VERBOSE: LookbackDate: Tuesday, May 3, 2016
Saturday, April 30, 2016 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: Wao!! Thanks, that's impressive. Can i store the days in the output to independent variables? For ex: at the moment the output is Wed, Thus, Fri & Sat. In this case i want the output to only have Thus, Fri & Sat and have them stored in 3 different variables $day1 = "Thus" $day2 = Fri $day3 = Sat .. Also i want these variables to have them stored in yyyymmdd format?